# How can I create multiple references sections?

Tags: bibliographies, thesis

I would like to know how can I create two or more section of references within my thesis document. I'm using the OCIAM thesis format from Oxford. I'm using natbib and Harvard referencing style. 
In other words, I need to put the references separately for each one of the papers that I'm including in my thesis.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use the `multibib` package or alternatively, switch to `biblatex` which can do this easily. See [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660) and [Per-chapter bibliographies in biblatex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/87414)

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Bibliographies_per_Section_or_Chapter